# PHP Deleting multiple rows with returning values to another table

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a code here that deletes a single row of data from `sales_order` and then returns the value of the `qty` to the products table.

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    //get values from href
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $invoice=$_GET['invoice'];
    $qty=$_GET['qty'];
    $product=$_GET['product'];

    //returns quantity to stock
    $sql = "UPDATE products
            SET stock=stock+?
            WHERE productid=?";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($qty,$product));

    //execute query
    $result = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM sales_order WHERE transaction_id= :id");
    $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $result->execute();
    header("location:pos.php?invoice=$invoice");
?>
```

Now what I'm aiming to do here is to have a reset button that will delete all rows with the same invoice number from sales_order and then each row returns the quantity value to the products table. I can't seem to find a way to do it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE products AS p
JOIN sales_order AS s on s.productid = p.productid
SET p.stock = p.stock + s.quantity
WHERE s.invoice_number = :invoice
```

Then you can delete all the `sales_order` rows with that invoice number. You should use a transaction to ensure that this is all done atomically.

I'm making some assumptions above about the schemas of the tables, you'll need to adjust to your actual column names.

Comment: I just got the time to code now so im saying this late but the code worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can go with an array concept. I think its simple to retrieve all the required values using select query before deletion. Then you can save it to the required tables. The you can delete the values